# The page keeps on refreshing when finally logged in

Tags: javascript, jquery

So me and my group are trying to make a website where the user has to sign up and login and they will go to a new html page and it checks whether the user is logged on or not,  We're using firebase and we don't know why the page keeps on refreshing constantly.. this is our code below.

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
     console.log("Logged in");
 window.location.href = "home.html";
 return false;
    }
  
 else {
     console.log("Not Logged in");
    }
});
```

Comment: Just going off the logic, it would suggest user is being passed in as something other than null, undefined, empty string, empty array, or false.

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out???